# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal server error

Tags: php, soap

I'm doing a work with web service.

i made a code but I cannot get that to work on my localhost.

this is the complete error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Interno del Servidor in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\soap.php:13 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://ws.punta...', 'EQUITALSYSGXVac...', 1, 0) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\soap.php(13): SoapClient->__soapCall('Execute', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\soap.php on line 13
```

and this is my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("awsabofactura001.wsdl");



$result = $client->__soapCall("Execute", array(
    "parameters" => array(
        "Usrid"  => "WEBCA",
        "Usrpass" => "test" ,
     )));

echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php 1. turn on exceptions and tracing 2. don't call __soapCall() directly. Use $client->Execute() and pass your params in.

Comment: Mike I tried to do it, but it still give me the same error

Comment: The problem is on the server side, not on the client side, although it may be a picky server which errors out on incorrect input rather then actually using the SOAP protocol to tell you about incorrect input.